# Error replacing \ with \\

Tags: javascript

I want to make a replace the \ in a string for \

Im doing this:

```
string.replace (/\\/g, '\\\');
```

But It doesnt work.

For example: "Text using the \ character" is not replaced.

If I use

```
string.replace (/\\/g, 'ZZZ');
```

the result is `"Text using the ZZZ character".`

Comment: `'\\\');` is a syntax error.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. It's basic Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be aware that you're escaping the `\` itself, and add additional `\`s to compensate.

The first thing to note is that you generally want an *even* number of them, because — to take this case as an example — with `'\\\'` you're writing one `\` and then escaping the closing `'`, breaking the entire code line.

So:

```
string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
//              ^      ^ ^
//              |      | |
//     one \ to escape | |
//         in regex    | |
//                     | |
//             one \ to escape in
//         string, for EACH of your two
//              new backslashes
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need 4 backslashes:

`string.replace (/\\/g, '\\\\');`

And then it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gmQg3/

Answer (score 0):

You have miss a `\` into the second argument of replace function, only `\\\` generate an error
try this:

```
var replaced = str.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, instead:

```
string.replace (/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

You are missing a backslash in your replaced string.
Make sure that you always have even number of backslashes in a double quoted string.
A simple way to remember this is that each pair of backslashes represent an actual backslash character, when used in this way (though, this is not really whats going on here). :)